# Unable to redirect back even after successful login using Okta widget

Tags: reactjs, okta, signing

I am using Okta Sign In widget for authentication but even after successful login there is no redirection instead it keeps loading for unlimited time

these are my configs:

```
oidc: {
    url: 'https://{yourOktaDomain}',
    issuer: 'https://{yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default',
    redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/implicit/callback`,
    clientId: `{clientId}`,
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
    pkce: true
  },
  postLogoutRedirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/login`
```

and these are widget initialization:

```
    const { issuer, clientId, redirectUri, scopes, url } = config.oidc;
    const widget = new OktaSignIn({
      baseUrl: url,
      clientId,
      redirectUri,
      logo: '/react.svg',
      i18n: {
        en: {
          'primaryauth.title': 'Sign in using Okta',
        },
      },
      authParams: {
        issuer,
        scopes,
      },
    });
```

I have already added trusted origin in Okta Console:

[Trusted origins image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcoMc.png)

Also, already added Redirection URIs in Okta Application:

[Redirection URIs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYMWP.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should ask a question in question-posts.

Comment: Does your redirectUri match what you have defined in your Okta application to be the Login redirect URI?